# How to check three Auth in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I create 3 auth in laravel 5.2,

Admin -> admin,

Site -> couple, vendor.

And use this code for find Auth in site:

```
@if(Auth::guard('vendor')->check())
         <li><a href="{{ Route('vendor.dashboard.index') }}">Vendor profile</a></li>
     @endif
     @if(Auth::guard('couple')->check())
         <li><a href="{{ Route('couple.dashboard.index') }}">couple profile</a></li>
     @endif
     @if(Auth::guard('couple')->check() != true && Auth::guard('vendor')->check() != true )
         <li><a href="{{ Route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
         <li><a href="{{ Route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
     @else
         <li><a href="{{ Route('logout') }}">Exit</a></li>
@endif
```

But this code is error !

How to check vendor Auth and couple Auth in my project?

Comment: What error youa are getting